# Using Archimedian property to prove that infimum of set is $0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, self-learning

Given set A = [ $\frac{1}{n} | n \in \mathbb{N}$]

It seems to me i have to prove two things :

1. $\frac{1}{n} \geq 0 , \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

2, Assuming $b$ be another lower bound , and so $b \leq 0$

Work :

1 Now $\frac{1}{n} \geq 0 , \forall n \in N$

Also $n \geq 1$

So $\frac{1}{n} \leq 1$ . But $\frac{1}{n} \in R^+$. So, $0 < \frac{1}{n} \leq
 1$

2. Assume that $b > 0$

so by Archimedian property $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$
 such that $\frac{1}{n} < b$ which is contradiction to the fact that b is lower bound for the set

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ is a lower bound, $ 1/n >0$, $n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$.

Assume $b >0$, real,  is a lower bound.

Archimedean principle:

There is a $n_0 \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ s.t.

$n_0  >1/b$, i.e.

$b > 1/n_0$, a contradiction(Why?).

Hence $\inf (A)=0$.

Comment: please check my attempt

Comment: J.Deff.I 1/n >0, 0 is a lower bound.Ok?To show that 0 is the greatest lower bound you assume a lower bound b that is bigger. 0< 1/n, and assuming it is not the greatesower bound you pick b >0 , and contradict.You choose b<0, a smaller lower bound. b <0 <1/n automatically.Let me know.

Comment: Check my proof now please and let me know

Comment: Deff.You got it. I would put in an extra line, Archimedean principle: There is a n >1/b ( real).Then b >1/n, i.e. a little more explicit on the Arch.principle.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that 0 is a lower bound of $\frac{1}{n}$
Archimedian property- if $x > 0 $ then there exists $n \epsilon \mathbb{R} $ such that $nx > y; x,y \epsilon \mathbb{R}$. Set $x = \epsilon$ and $y=1$ $$ \epsilon > \frac{1}{n} \forall \epsilon > 0$$ . Hence infimum of $\frac{1}{n} $ is $0$ .

Comment: I dont understand this version of archimedian property.I have following version which is 
:...Given there is any rela number b then there exists some natural number n such that $n > b$

Comment: Just search archimedian property for real nos. on Google. You'll get this version of archimedian property.